# Why does my program always find a class but if I search for this class in the HTML it does not exist?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

So the problem is that if i search manually for the class = "warn" it only finds it if the seller does not have the card. That is because the text which says, that the card is not available has that class.
But the program below always give me TRUE even if the Seller does sell the card and the class ="warn" is not found.

I already looked if it is just because the "do you accept our Cookies?" bar also have the class but I already tried that programthe does not look for the "warn clickable" class.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\chrome_driver_73\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/MainPage/browseUserProducts?idCategory=1&idUser=10000&resultsPage=0&cardName=dasfsaf&idLanguage=0&isFoil=0&isSigned=0&isPlayset=0&isAltered=0")
def check_if_card_exists():
    try :
         driver.find_element_by_class_name('warn')
         return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False

print(check_if_card_exists())
```

So the Output of this Code is TRUE which is good, but if insert a cardname where it actual shows a result like ......resultsPage=0&cardName=Opt.... it also prints TRUE but in the HTML code I do not find class = 'warn'.
The full Url with the card opt:
https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/MainPage/browseUserProducts?idCategory=1&idUser=10000&resultsPage=0&cardName=Opt&idLanguage=0&isFoil=0&isSigned=0&isPlayset=0&isAltered=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Looks like there is a class with 'warn'.

Comment: So is there a funktion in swlenium where i can exactly look for the class='warn' and not warn clickable?

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(“//*[@class=‘warn’]”)` - Try this.